# Duplicate vowels in a string

Tags: c++, string

I have a string of 100 elements and I have to duplicate every vowel whenever I find one and add it to the next position in the string . The problem is if there are two vowels on two consecutive position in the string it won't work.

This is what I've tried :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char p[200];
    int i=0,n;
    cin.get(p,200);
    while(i<strlen(p)){
        if(strchr("aeiou",p[i])) {
            strcpy(p+i+2,p+i+1);
            p[i+1]=p[i];
            i=i+2;

        }
        else i++;
    }
    cout<<p;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with std::string?

Comment: by two vocals u mean vowels right?

Comment: @lazer_wizard not really

Comment: Add an example output to show that it's wrong?

Comment: and what did the debugger show was happening

Answer (score 3):

You are using `strcpy` wrong here.

The method is not safe to use on overlapping buffers.  You're writing to memory before you read it, causing weird behavior.

You need to either use `memmove`, write your own loop to copy the characters, or use two different character buffers for input and result instead of just p.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with `strcpy`. It copies values onr by one, so after `p[i]` is copied into `p[i+1]`, the new value of `p[i+1]` is copied into `p[i+2]`, and so on. So the string will then contain only the `p[i]`.

You may want to use another array for destination string, and copy one character each time. This will also avoid many `strcpy` calls, hence save time.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char p[100] = {0};
    char dest[200] = {0};
    cin.get(p, 100);
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while(p[i]){
        if (strchr("aeiou",p[i])) {
            dest[j++] = p[i];
        }
        dest[j++] = p[i++];
    }
    cout << dest;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you take advantage of C++ std objects, your code looks more C. std::string provides access and modification methods which are easier to use than c arrays, same for std::vectors.

A quick example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::string editStr = "qweertadoi";
std::vector<char> vowels{'i', 'o', 'u', 'e', 'a'};

int main() {

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i<editStr.size(); i++){
        for(char c: vowels){
            if(editStr.at(i) == c){
                editStr.insert(i++,1, c);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << editStr << std::endl; 
    return 0;
}
```